# MongoParseError: option useCreateIndex is not supported

Tags: mongodb

I tried to run the server in my MERN project but it gives me a MongoParseError.
My code is,

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

module.exports = async() => {
  try {
    const connectionParams = {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    };
    await mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/todo-app", connectionParams);
    console.log("Connected to database.");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Could not able to connect to database.", error);
  }
};
```

And the error message was,

```
Listening on port ${port}...
Could not able to connect to database. MongoParseError: option usecreateindex is not supported
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs due to the Deprecation Warning Options.
To avoid this:

1. Remove `useCreateIndex: true,`
2. Now run the server.

You can also try:

1. Remove entire `const connectionParams = {....};`
2. Remove the comma and  `connectionParams` parameter.
3. Now run the server.

Your final code should look like:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

module.exports = async() => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/todo-app");
    console.log("Connected to database.");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Could not able to connect to database.", error);
  }
};
```

Because `useNewUrlParser`, `useUnifiedTopology`, `useFindAndModify`, and `useCreateIndex` are no longer supported options. Mongoose 6 always behaves as if `useNewUrlParser`, `useUnifiedTopology`, and `useCreateIndex` are `true`, and `useFindAndModify` is `false`. So please remove these options from your code.

for more clarifications refer [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#no-more-deprecation-warning-options)